# регулярка python

Tags: python

Никак не могу понять как в пайтоне работают регулярки.
Помогите пожалуйста понять одну базовую задачу.
Допустим есть строка: "привет, я мирон123" и мне нужно вывести "мирон123"
В Lua всё было ясно: `text = text.match("привет, я (.+)")`, как это же будет в пайтоне?

Comment: [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: пожалуйста, можно в виде кода именно эту строку, чтобы я понимал как можно перевести регулярку с луа в пайтон

Comment: Язык регулярных выражений не зависит от языка программирования.

Comment: но почему то мне не удается повторить обычный код с луа здесь)

Comment: Тогда стоит привести ваш код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст всегда найдётся, то можно просто:

```
import re
text = "привет, я мирон123"
text = re.findall(r"привет, я (.+)", text)[0]
```

Но в случае не соответствия исходной строки паттерну будет вызвано исключение. Можно не брать нулевой элемент, а сначала проверить, что функция вернула не None, и действовать по ситуации.

Ну или если надо, чтобы всё-равно что-то вернуло, то как вариант:

```
text = next(iter(re.findall(r"привет, я (.+)", text)), "")
```

Comment: Почему не `re.match` ? `re.findall` делает намного больше чем простое сопоставление.